# PHP SCript Not Accepting AJAX Data

Tags: php, ajax

This is really bizarre. I am trying to submit data to the server and have a PHP script parse the data and then send back a response. A correctly formed URL is being sent:

```
http://localhost/ajax/test.html?row=rec_no_1
```

, but the server does not seem to respond with content from the PHP script despite a return code of 200. In fact, Developer Tools (in Google Chrome) doesn't say anything about the PHP file. The AJAX "data" statement must be formatted properly otherwise I wouldn't get the correct URL. POST (instead of GET) doesn't help.

If I change the AJAX data to a string, then it works fine. This implies there is something wrong with the AJAX data. But I can't understand what given that the URL is correctly formed and does change depending on which row I select.

Any ideas?

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".submit").click(function() {

$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getTable.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {row: $('input[type='checkbox']:checked').val()},
        //data: {row: 'rec_no_2'},
        success: function($result) {
    $('.tableHolder').text($result);
    }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['row'])) {
    $tableRow = $_GET['row'];
    echo $tableRow;
}
else
        echo 'TEST';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect:

```
$('input[type='checkbox']:checked').val()
```

You should use double quotes around `checkbox`:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val()
```

Anyway do a `console.log( $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val() )` before the ajax call just to find out which value is being sent.

Comment: That's it, it works. Thank you very much. All the books I have been reading so far have mentioned that a person should use single-quotes in their Javascript and double-quotes in their HTML. I guess this is one of those ODD cases where statements like that are flat out wrong. With subtleties like this it is no wonder that so many questions get asked on Stackoverflow. Thank you again and have a great day!!!!

Comment: @user1650586 you're welcome :)) By the way you may use single and double quotes wherever you want [both html and js], but for example if you need double quotes **inside** your string, you must use single quotes as delimiters, and viceversa - no oddity at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your javascript file to server. Ajax don't work on cross domain. You are running the javascript file on localhost and trying to fetch information from live server. Keep both php and javascript file on same server, either live or localhost. It will work fine.

One more thing, try changing the url parameter of your ajax request. try complete url or try putting or not putting a slash / before your filename.

Comment: The Javascript file is on the server along with the PHP file. "Localhost" just means the server (which is Apache via XAMPP) is running on the same machine I am using my web browser from. There is nothing wrong with this and it should not impose any problems. I do testing on my local machine like this all the time. I have tried the URL both ways. This does not help. Besides, I mentioned that it works fine when I change the AJAX data to a string instead of the check for a checkbox being selected.